# Why php curl uses forked apache processes and php_start_session()?

Tags: php, apache, curl

I am working on a php script which does several thousands of http calls to another server using curl. I noticed continous increasing of the number of apache processes while running a similar to the below php code:

```
$ch = curl_init($this->server);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
```

After a while I checked some of the running apache processes using gdb and for many of them I got backtraces like this:

```
#0  0x00007fa1fec1d617 in flock () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fa1fbbaf53b in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#2  0x00007fa1fbbaf7a2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#3  0x00007fa1fbbae524 in php_session_start () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#4  0x00007fa1fbbaebb9 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#5  0x00007fa1fbd6fe8d in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#6  0x00007fa1fbd209fb in execute () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#7  0x00007fa1fbcfbf60 in zend_execute_scripts () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#8  0x00007fa1fbca85d3 in php_execute_script () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#9  0x00007fa1fbd8b46d in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#10 0x00007fa1ffa12508 in ap_run_handler ()
#11 0x00007fa1ffa1297e in ap_invoke_handler ()
#12 0x00007fa1ffa21c1c in ap_internal_redirect ()
#13 0x00007fa1f9f74635 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
#14 0x00007fa1ffa12508 in ap_run_handler ()
#15 0x00007fa1ffa1297e in ap_invoke_handler ()
#16 0x00007fa1ffa225b0 in ap_process_request ()
#17 0x00007fa1ffa1f3d8 in ?? ()
#18 0x00007fa1ffa18fa8 in ap_run_process_connection ()
#19 0x00007fa1ffa27210 in ?? ()
#20 0x00007fa1ffa2797a in ?? ()
#21 0x00007fa1ffa28527 in ap_mpm_run ()
#22 0x00007fa1ff9fd4a4 in main ()
```

So it looks like, using curl results in starting new php session. Since I am using some legacy included php code, which does session_start() but does not use session_write_close(), I can understand that such a process can not end. So I put session_write_close() before curl_init() call, and then the number of apache processes remained low.

All the curl calls are working, all the http calls are successful, data arrives, etc.

So I ended up with several unanswered question:

- Why using php curl results in forked apache processes?
- Why php curl uses php_start_session(), even if in the new apache processes?
- How can all the curl functions be successful, but at the minimum, how can
  the http transfer be successful, if it any way needs a forked apache
  process which is however stucked at php_start_session()?

Comment: I really don't believe that curl uses php_start_session(). Most probably session is started by some other PHP code or session.auto_start is set in configuration.

Comment: Also the GDB output suggests, that this particular Apache child is waiting for session lock to be released and nothing suggests that it has something to do with curl.

Comment: Yes, from the backtrace nothing suggests it, even so it happens. In the relevant php.ini the session.auto_start is set to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your encountered issues have anything to do with the usage of curl.

The default PHP configuration concerning sessions is a file-based session storage mechanism. Access to files is exclusive. This has the effect that every single session can only be used by one script at a time. If a second scripts calls `session_start()` with the same session id, it will block at that call, until the first script finishes its execution and closes the session file. The result would (or could) be that you may see a rise in waiting processes, especially if one tries to access the website again and again while all requests block.

The solution to this problem is to close the session handler as soon as it is not needed anymore (with [`session_write_close`](http://www.php.net/session_write_close)) and especially before time consuming tasks (like sending a file with [`readfile()`](http://www.php.net/readfile) or performaing long running CURL requests).

Therefore your solution seems fine to me, just the explanation went in the wrong direction.

Comment: There were no any remarkable request to the server of the time running this several thousands of curl request from this server. I see your point of view and I know about php session handling is done by file locks. It just so, that while there are no request to this server, but there are curl request from this server, the number of apache processes are increasing. I tested it several times. Sounds like non-sense I know. That is why I am asking for any idea.

Comment: Replace the curl calls with `sleep(10);` and see if this changes anything. `grep` your source code for `session_start` and remove unnecessary occurrences, may make sense too.

Comment: Also, how do you detect that there are no any remarkable requests to the server during the curl "inferno"? Are you looking for access.log or server status. Because requests are logged to the access.log after the request finishes, which means there are no lines while the requests are in the queue.

Comment: Btw. you are basically telling us that you do a few thousand curl requests inside an apache process? Are you starting the script automatically via external cron e.g. every minute? Together with the old `session_start` calls, this will create a lot of processes.

Comment: I tried the sleep() trick and it helped me think forward. After a while I realized that curl really has nothing to do with my problem, and actually I forgot that not only a few includes are legacy, but a running html site with javascript making request periodically. I just skipped its entries in the access.log by mistake. I was concentrating on the several thousands repeating part (curl). I am accepting the answer as a "thank you" and because really only session_start() calls and incoming requests caused the problem. Any idea on what should I do with this wrong question now?

Comment: According to the guidelines you can just leave it as it is right now.